# Uninstall Python 3.x on osx

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, uninstallation, macos-sierra

I have now installed three Python versions on my Mac (3, 3.4 and 3.6) in /usr/local/bin. How do uninstall versions 3 and 3.4 manually?